# How do I approach the problem if Cp is given as a function of volume?

Tags: thermodynamics, enthalpy, specific-heat

Here is the problem I'm trying to solve:

> A system undergoes Isothermal Expansion under the atmosphere. For the system, $ C_p = a + \frac{b}{V} \ $. The process is given by $ P_{ATM}, V_1, T_1 \rightarrow P_{ATM}, V_2, T_1 $. Calculate the change in internal energy

The first thing I notice is that this is clearly not an ideal gas. The first approach I could think of was to somehow use $ C_p $ to find $ \Delta H \ \text{(using} \ C_p = (\frac{\delta H}{\delta T})_P) \ $ and then use $ \Delta H = \Delta U + P \Delta V \ $ but I ran into a problem since $ C_p $ is given as a function of volume.

I realised later that this is equivalent to using the first law of thermodynamics: since pressure is constant, $ q = q_p = \int_{T_1}^{T_1} C_p \ dT$ which seems to just be zero, and so my answer $ \Delta U = q_p - P \Delta V = - P \Delta V $.

This is the best I could do, but I'm not convinced since I'm getting very confused and I think my concepts are extremely off. Any clarification/assistance is much appreciated.
Also, in general (since this was an exceptional case where my integral limits were the same) how do I evaluate the integral if $ C_p $ is given as a function of volume?

Thanks!

Comment: As it is isothermal AND isobaric expansion, the volume change is possible only due a chemical reaction or a phase change. And therefore there is unclear heat exchange, depending on the enthalpy change of reaction/phase change.

Comment: I think this made up task is badly defined.

Comment: Yes, it seems to violate the equation of state.

Comment: @Poutnik This was part of our homework assignment - our professor clarified that the system is not an ideal gas. From what I discussed with my peers, we couldn't really come up with anything substantial either. Again, the best we could think of doing is to just say that change in enthalpy is 0 (which is unconvincing (for the reasons mentioned above - I don't really know how to solve an integral from partial derivatives). 
If you have any other advice, please let me know, thanks!